# ASP.Net page loading

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a asp.net page in which i have 3 dropdown's each dropdown takes 30k rows from a storedprocedure. The storedprocedure takes 8 seconds to execute and populate the rows which is the datasource for those dropdowns. Now seeing this my page should take at max 15 seconds to render and load but it is taking 25 seconds can any one help on this.

Comment: Page has just 3 controls? Nothing else? It wil be difficult for us to give you options because there could be many reasons. Did you try client side/server side profiling tools?

Comment: If you use linq to SQL - this is much slower than SQL queries.

Comment: I am directly binding the dropdown to a DataTable

Comment: Shoban there are other controls which does not require to load from database only problem is with these three dropdowns's

Answer (score 2):

To load this amount of data on drop down list, is first of all bad user internface because no one can search on drop down list to find this among 30k of lines, and also the browser suffer try to handle this data.

The most easy way that I suggest is to change the drop down list to  **auto complete** control.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Having a dropdown list of that size is quite concerning in regards to usability and performance as you have noticed. I think your best option is to have a look at alternatives such as telerik's combo box (pricey) or ASP.NET Ajax's autocompete:

- http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/combobox.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Hope that helps.